# MVC 4 - Trying to remove jquery mobile from my site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, kendo-ui

So I have a website which has the following script bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Jquery/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/Jquery/jquery.fn.extend-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
            //"~/Scripts/Jquery/Mobile/jquery.mobile-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js",
            "~/Scripts/knockout.validation-min.js",
            "~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.js",
            "~/Scripts/knockout.kendo-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*",
            "~/Scripts/mdetect.js"
        ));
```

So the problem I am having is this - when that query.mobile is commented out my stuff with the kendo ui grid disappear. How can I remedy this? I have scoured the web but perhaps I am not searching the right way.

Comment: Kind of cheezy when people can't repsonse.

Comment: ): Quite a disappointed response. 
(:I figured it out.

Comment: Maybe nobody knows. If you figured it out you should post the answer below, maybe others have this problem as well.

Comment: @Marthijn - Yeah, and if I post maybe you can take away the negative vote please...

Answer (score 0):

Solution was this -
MY solution is using knockout.js and jquery mobile. In order to load models when the page loads, jquery needs to subscribe to the page init event, which loads and binds the initial model. Well, after removing jquery mobile, it was as simple as removing $(document).on("pageinit"...